# search by http request to a third-party server in Drupal 8

Tags: full-text-search, drupal-8

guys.
I have a site built by Drupal which core version is 8.9.20.
And I have a search server built by other which can be request over https.

So, how can I use this search server to be my search api in my site?

I've tried to create a custom module, but don't know how to fill it.